# Remove Firefox glow on focused textarea

Tags: css, firefox, textarea

I can't figure this one out. I'm trying to get rid of that blue glow when `textarea` is highlighted in Firefox.

Here's my CSS:

```css
textarea
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width: 598px;
    height: 600px;
    resize: none;
    outline: none;
}

:focus {
      outline:0;
      outline:none;
}
```

It removes it in Safari, but I'm have no luck with Firefox.

Thanks!
Matt

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can remove it with `-moz-appearance:none;`, though that may affect the whole appearance more than you're wanting.

Comment: Beautiful.. Thanks! It just removes it on all textarea's which is fine.

Answer (score 30):

how about

```css
*:focus {outline:0px none transparent;}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, in modern Firefox versions (tested with FF 21 on Mac OS X) `outline` doesn't influence the blue "glow" around a focused `<input>` at all: http://jsbin.com/elukeq/1/edit

Comment: `textarea, textarea:hover, textarea:focus, textarea:active {border:none; outline:none;}` will better suite this case

Answer (score 7):

If you use this on the textarea style:

```
outline:none;
```

... it should work with all browsers, not just Firefox

Answer (score 2):

I'm fairly sure that's a Mac OS X theme-specific behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Just add or define a border... for instance, if a border is defined and I've added outline: none; to my CSS, this does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I just had an issue with this on a text input- Firefox was using the border property to create the blue glow on :focus - not outline.

```
input:focus, textarea:focus {
  outline: none; // for other browsers
  border: none; // only necessary if you haven't set a border on the element
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove the glow in Firefox I think.. Only way to do that would be by adding a custom border to your element, like `border: 1px black;`, that would make the input box have no glow at all.

Only *popular* browsers which allows the `outline` tag are Safari and Chrome (not sure about linux browsers).

Comment: Outline is supported by IE as well.

Answer (score 0):

The better way to fix this, in my opinion, is define a custom border and `:focus` behavior.

```
textarea {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width: 598px;
    height: 600px;
    resize: none;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
}

textarea:focus {
      outline: none;
      border: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

on #3

```
   #Solution0:focus{
      border:solid #CCC 1px;
      outline:1px none transparent;
   }
```

​

Answer (score 0):

Slightly unrelated but possibly helpful answer:  In my case the blue glow was causing an alignment problem in Firefox only since it adds an extra pixel or two and changes the overall element size.  My guess is a lot of people will arrive at this question for similar reasons and rather than remove the blue glow altogether, the solution I came to was to style the input element padding in specifically for Firefox:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    input:focus {
        padding: 5px!important;
    }
}
```

You can change this to suite your needs but it may be helpful for some of you to know about the `@-moz-document url-prefix()` rule.